# How to Grab meaning of sentence using NLP?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy, textblob

I am new to **NLP**. My requirement is to parse meaning from sentences.

**Example**

1. "Perpetually Drifting is haunting in all the best ways."
2. "When The Fog Rolls In is a fantastic song

From above sentences, I need to extract the following sentences

1. "haunting in all the best ways."
2. "fantastic song"

Is it possible to achieve this in `spacy`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to extract the summarized sentences using spacy. I hope the following methods might work for you

- Simplest one is extract the noun phrases or verb phrases. Most of the time that should give the text what you want.(Phase struce grammar).
- You can use dependency parsing and extract the center word dependencies.
  [dependency grammar](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-dependency-parse)
- You can train an sequence model where input is going to be the full sentence and output will be your summarized sentence.
  [Sequence models for text summaraization](https://machinelearningmastery.com/encoder-decoder-models-text-summarization-keras/)

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the meaning of a sentence is a quite arbitrary task. What do you mean by the meaning? Using spaCy you can extract the dependencies between the words (which specify the meaning of the sentence), find the POS tags to check how words are used in the sentence and also find places, organizations, people using NER tagger. However, meaning of the sentence is too general even for the humans.

Maybe you are searching for a specific meaning? If that's the case, you have to train your own classifier. [This](https://spacy.io/api/textcategorizer) will get you started.

If your task is summarization of a couple of sentences, consider also using gensim . You can have a look [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/summarization/summariser.html).

Hope it helps :)