# Question about how to shorten a long sentence while keeping its semantic meaning

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

We are building a NLP system to compare semantic similarity between two sentences. Before sentence embedding, we'd like to 'shorten/compress' the sentences a bit because it is quite long.

Can we know how to shorten a long sentence in NLP task while keeping the semantic meaning of the sentence as much as possible? We've known a possible and simplest solution which uses a sliding window to extract various chunks from the input sentence:

For example, the input sentence is `In June 2017 Kaggle announced that it passed 1 million registered users.`. Several chunks can be extracted as follows:

```
In June 2017 Kaggle announced that # chunk 1
announced that it passed 1 million # chunk 2
1 million registered users # chunk 3
```

Actually, this method may lose some semantic information of the sentence. Except for this simplest way, is there any other smarter way to shorten the sentence while keep semantic meaning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a ton of experience with NLP Systems but I would approach this in one of two ways to get your desire outcome (if I understand correctly):

#### 1. Find what defines sentences for you, for me I would do:

- in English, subject-verb is required;
- conjunctions, subjunctions, etc. are mostly unnecessary;
- prepositions are unnecessary;
- etc...

#### 2. Check out this other post on Stack Overflow to see how you could extract meanings:

- [How to Grab meaning of sentence using NLP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52280334/21798546) with spacy.io
- Once you extract meanings, create your criteria like above and potentially run it througha regex
- This might help with the [NLTK package](https://realpython.com/nltk-nlp-python)

And this can vary drastically depending on what you need but I hope this helps guide you towards a path that best serves you.

Answer (score 1):

-This code helps to shorten the sentence and also try to keep the semantic meaning , hope it helps you

```
import spacy

#Load the English language model in spaCy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

#Define a function to get the meaning of a sentence
def get_meaning(sentence):

   # Parse the sentence using spaCy
   doc = nlp(sentence)

   # Extract the main verb of the sentence
   main_verb = [token for token in doc if token.pos_ == 'VERB'][0]

   # Extract the main subject of the sentence
   main_subject = [token for token in doc if token.dep_ == 'nsubj'][0]

   # Extract the meaning of the sentence
   meaning = main_verb.lemma_ + " " + main_subject.lemma_

   return meaning

#Example sentence
sentence = "In June 2017 Kaggle announced that it passed 1 million 
registered users.."

#Get the meaning of the sentence
meaning = get_meaning(sentence)

#Print the sentence and its meaning
print("Sentence:", sentence)
print("Meaning:", meaning)

#Output:

Sentence: In June 2017 Kaggle announced that it passed 1 million registered users..

Meaning: announce Kaggle
```